# What should this definition be?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, universal-property

This is from *Advanced Linear Algebra* by S.Roman.

> **Definition (on page 356).** Referring to the figure below, let A be a set and let $\mathcal S$ be a family of sets. Let
>   $$ \mathcal F = \{g\colon A\to X \mid X\in\mathcal S \} $$
>   be a family of functions, all of which have domain $A$ and range a member of $\mathcal S$.
>   Let
>   $$ \mathcal H = \{ \tau \colon X \to Y \mid X,Y \in \mathcal S \} $$
>   be a family of functions with domain and range in $\mathcal S$.
>
> We assume that $\mathcal H$ has the following structure:
>
> 1. $\mathcal H$ contains the identity function $\iota_S$ for each member of $\mathcal S$.
> 2. $\mathcal H$ is closed under composition of functions, which is an associative operation.
> 3. For any $\tau \in \mathcal H$ and $f \in \mathcal F$, the composition $\tau\circ f$ is defined and belongs to $\mathcal F$.
>
>    [image]
>
> We refer to $\mathcal H$ as the **measuring family** and its members as **measuring funcitons**.

I do not understand property 3 in the definition.

However this actually contradicts the diagram (consider picking $\tau_2$ and $f_2$, then $\tau_2\circ f_2$ isn't defined)

My question is: what does it mean to say?

I've tried searching for terms like "measuring family universal property" but I either get property management stuff, stuff on measuring family functioning, or a link to Google books. I've looked in the index and scanned through Categories for the working mathematician and haven't found it either. I'd like to be sure about this before proceeding (and not have to guess looking at proofs and the desired properties)

Comment: I don't know the notion described here, but my two cents is that property 3 is far to restrictive as it implies that all functions of $\mathcal F$ have the same range and all functions of $\mathcal H$ have the same domain (as soon as $\mathcal F$ is not empty). Then, by property 1, $\mathcal S$ must be a singleton... Possibly, the author wants a property 3 like : for all $\tau \in \mathcal H$ and $f \in \mathcal F$, if the composite $\tau \circ f$ is defined, then it is a member of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: The notion is that of a sieve (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_(category_theory)) on an object. In this case you want a subset of $\hom(X,Y)$ which is a sort of 'ideal' under composition; the only compositions that are defined are from 'subobjects' of X, which sort of means that the sieve is trying to act as a 'cover' for $\hom(X,Y)$. These notions lead to the definition of a grothendieck topology on a category (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_topology).

As for the specific example of this in the case, i have no idea, sorry. :(

Comment: Please, write your answers as answers, not as comments!

Comment: @Pece that goes double for you, you need upvotes for the edit! (I feel both guilty and grateful)